# using a guard with a list haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-stack

So I have a function that takes

```
otherfunction :: Int -> Bool
otherfunction = True
```

Implementation of `otherfunction` doesn't matter

```
function :: [Int] -> world -> world
function listOfInts World | [otherfunction x <- listOfInts] = world {alive = False}
                    | otherwise world
```

so if any of the `otherfunction(x)` in `listOfInts` returns a `False` I want it to do that world {alive is False} , how can I implement this? I can maybe do `False`elem`[otherfunction x <- listOfInts]`, is there a better way to do this in Haskell.

Thanks for the much needed help, I am new to functional programming.

Comment: In Haskell `False` and `True` ar with uppercase, as well as the types (given these are not type variables).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`all`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:all):

```
function :: [int] -> world -> world
function listOfInts world
  | all otherfunction listOfInts = world
  | otherwise                    = world {alive = false}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just set `world` as the `&&` with the `all otherfunction` of this list, like:

```
function :: [Int] -> World -> World
function listOfInts world = world {alive = alive world && allOther }
    where allOther = all otherfunction listOfInts
```

So from the moment one of the `listOfInts` has an element `i` where `otherfunction i` returns `False`, `all otherfunction listOfInts` will return `False`, and thus we change the `alive` of the world.

We can also use a conditional expression:

```
function :: [Int] -> World -> World
function listOfInts world | alive world && not allOther = world {alive = False }
                          | otherwise = world
    where allOther = all otherfunction listOfInts
```

We can also omit the `alive world` check. But that means that if the world is already dead, we might do a lot of precessing in the list, that is not necessary.